How to get an actual type object with generic class?
I get an error with Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.test.QueryOrderInfo
bizContent is a json String, I want to parse it to an QueryOrderInfo object.
update:
Now I add fromJson2() method, and it work well. But why it throw exception in fromJson() method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseResponse<QueryOrderInfo> queryOrderInfoBaseResponse = null;
        try {
            queryOrderInfoBaseResponse = new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"returnCode\":\"SUCCESS\",\"biz_content\":\"{\\\"mchReserved\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"cmbOrderId\\\":\\\"900119022715203210134445\\\",\\\"dscAmt\\\":\\\"0\\\",\\\"payType\\\":\\\"ZF\\\",\\\"orderId\\\":\\\"9001004180329103417277\\\",\\\"txnTime\\\":\\\"20190227152032\\\",\\\"merId\\\":\\\"3089991701207X7\\\",\\\"currencyCode\\\":\\\"156\\\",\\\"txnAmt\\\":\\\"1\\\",\\\"tradeState\\\":\\\"S\\\"}\",\"sign\":\"kGE7mwX/ubRlPsPZGNydjY3uCjILgGuxD4j1e/inyC/DlHn5o7LkISpmrH0YQvoZT6lyOxtr9uIkKnqVcTMZNYeYIBU+Tz8NRaPZHuFr/qQb0+fUgEgq5j9ovaFczAF8wrnEfIRYBEqp0ERtK7NG+X6eZLIr9nNVy31eKcnFx1tToJ/zPYN91GOKOtTrJaJrKeDY4+r3ctzsDhnD+TO2MX5zfvW0WLoUjvX5geiYLVpt022BiyxSJyOsrDS858RBmZ5FbVlYP0v/WqwX+J8VY1kDSLxvPtSZuPnsluJPXw6ccnYNH8dir0VgrYfrWRvnupctIm2elCmL7ES6KzDTGg==\",\"encoding\":\"UTF-8\",\"version\":\"0.0.1\",\"signMethod\":\"01\",\"respCode\":\"SUCCESS\"}", new TypeReference<BaseResponse<QueryOrderInfo>>() {
            });
            QueryOrderInfo queryOrderInfo = queryOrderInfoBaseResponse.fromJson();
QueryOrderInfo queryOrderInfo2 = queryOrderInfoBaseResponse.fromJson2(QueryOrderInfo.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

BaseResponse class
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BaseResponse<T> {

    private String returnCode;
    @JsonProperty(value = "biz_content")
    private String bizContent;
    private String sign;
    private String encoding;
    private String version;
    private String signMethod;
    private String respCode;

    private String errCode;
    private String respMsg;

    public T fromJson() {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(this.bizContent, new TypeReference<T>() {
            });
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

public T fromJson2(Class<T> clazz) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().readValue(this.bizContent, clazz);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class QueryOrderInfo {

    private String mchReserved;
    private String cmbOrderId;
    private String dscAmt;
    private String payType;
    private String orderId;
    private String txnTime;
    private String merId;
    private String currencyCode;
    private String txnAmt;
    private String tradeState;
}


It seems QueryOrderInfo is a single data object, while queryOrderInfoBaseResponse.fromJson()returns a multi data object. Can you provide the source code fromQueryOrderInfoeither?

@Reporter yes, it is a single data object. I post the source code of QueryOrderInfo

We aren't supposed to use TypeReference with type variables because it won't work due to Java Type Erasure.
So new TypeReference<T>() { }, this statement roughly equivalent to new TypeReference<Object>() { }
and that's why it mapped as LinkedHashMap if you got JSON Object.
I found this type conversion at times of deebug this issue. Hopefully this will help you to understand
why fromJson() throwing an exception.

You can more read about here
